# VBA Excel: Function to find a string in another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to create a function that searches a string (bom) in two different workbooks and returns a value next to that string. I know the ranges in those workbooks where I want to perform the search, and then use offset to get the value. However the function returns a #VALUE error.

I've created search functions before, but only within the same workbook, this is the first one using different workbooks. Maybe you can help me find an error in my logic:

```
Option Explicit

Function findhscode(bom As String)

Dim base1 As Workbook
Dim base2 As Workbook


base1 = Workbooks.Open("path1")
base2 = Workbooks.Open("path2")

If Not base1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("myRange").Find(bom) Is Nothing Then
    findhscode= base1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("myRange").Find(bom).Offset(0, -7).value
    Else
        If Not base2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("myRange").Find(bom) Is Nothing Then
        findhscode = base2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("myRange").Find(bom).Offset(0, 1).value
            Else
            findhscode= "Please contact Imports for assistance"
        End If
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Assigning objects `base1` and `base2` without `Set` works?

Comment: I added "set" but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out your code. In order to get it to work, you need to - as week suggests - set the base1 and base2 variables.  Otherwise you will get an:

*Object variable or With block variable not set* error.

It would also help (though it isn't causing the problem) if you assigned the return type in the function.  Because there is no explicit return type, it defaults to Object.   The only other thing I can think of is whether you have literal paths for base1 and base2 or you are using variables.  If variables, then remove the quotes.

The following code worked for me (with a couple MessageBox adds to give some debug info):

```
Function findhscode(bom As String)

Dim base1 As Workbook
Dim base2 As Workbook


Set base1 = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\book1.xlsx")
Set base2 = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\book2.xlsx")

  If Not base1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange").Find(bom) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "found in base1"
    findhscode = base1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange").Find(bom).Offset(0, 1).Value
    Else
        If Not base2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange").Find(bom) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "found in base2"
        findhscode = base2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange").Find(bom).Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else
            MsgBox "not found"
            findhscode = "Please contact Imports for assistance"
        End If
End If
```

I called this from a simple inputbox sub:

```
Sub stringPrompt()
  Dim hs As String
  hs = InputBox("String to search for", vbOKOnly, "Search String")
  Range("A1") = findhscode(hs)
End Sub
```

Note: the #Value error message usually indicates a data type error.  Have you checked that you are not trying to do a mathematical calculation with text data?

Also (only coz you mention the required value is 'next to that string').  Your first offset call is seven columns to the LEFT of that string.

Comment: Hello, I addet Set base1 but nothing changed, the paths are literals not variables, I'm not performing ani calculation either. The try to use the function by typing =findhscode() in a cell and then selecting the cell I want to look for. Regarding the offset 0, -7 it is ok because in that workbook the range containing the data is to the left.

Comment: Ahhhh, UDFs.  I don't think this is possible. From http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2007-HA010218996.aspx#BMusingvba:   ..., custom functions cannot resize windows; edit a formula in a cell; or change the font, color, or pattern options for the text in a cell. “action” code of this kind in a function procedure, returns the #VALUE! error.